# What exactly happens at the critical solution temperature of a phenol water system?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, phenols

What makes phenol that was turbid go clear beyond the critical solution temperature? We say beyond the critical solution temperature the constituents become soluble. What is the reaction or the exact change involved in the phenol water system (say with water in excess) beyond the critical solution temperature.

Comment: There is no reaction. As for the exact change... well, it's like you said: the components become soluble. I mean, they were soluble to some extent even before that point, but here they become soluble _infinitely_.

Comment: Critical Solution Temperature (CST)

Comment: In chemistry a system a two liquid system is said to have two phases. The system is turbid below the CST because one phase is droplets suspended in the other phase.